# bootstrap input type="date" not loading datepicker

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to use bootstrap input type 'date' to create an input field with a date picker but while the formatting for the input field appears to have been set by bootstrap's styling, it doesn't appear that the date picker is being implemented in that field.  when clicking into the field noting comes up and my typing is unrestricted.  Does this input type of date not natively create an input field with a type of date and make the input field a date picker?  [JSBIN Code Here](http://jsbin.com/yugimejasu/1/edit?html,output) My console shows no errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 box">
            <label>Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

if someone could explain why it's not working I would appreciate it.

Comment: It's browser dependent. In Chrome I see a caret to the right when hovering the input. When clicked a calendar appears. Input is also restricted to numbers in the format dd/mm/yyyy. This is a native browser control and nothing to do with Bootstrap.

Comment: Any thoughts on getting it to work in safari or do you have a different method you recommend that works better across browsers?

Comment: I've used this in the past https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Support is surprisingly poor for the built in controls http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: Why not using ui-bootstrap's date picker? [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4xz98VGpJmXBSPIgNI6b?p=preview)

Comment: Try this one: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native `<input type="date">` only works in a few browsers. IE is not one of them, although it does now work in Edge.
See the support table here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

You will need to use a polyfill library or datepicker JS plugin to get it to work everywhere. I recommend checking out Webshim: https://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/#Forms-forms-ext

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and IE at the moment do no support date type.

I found an easy fix for this thanks to the webshim library. I simply had to add the following line of code and everything worked fine. Note: webshim library depends on JQuery.

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.14.5/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script>
    webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
    webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
</script>
```